# In Vue, v-binding is not working on the "checked" property for Bootstrap Toggle Checkboxes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="id2" :checked="foo.bar">
```

The line of code above should check the input when `foo.bar` (which is a boolean) is 1 and uncheck the box when `foo.bar` is 0, but it never checks the box when the value is 1.

When I remove the `data-toggle="toggle"` from the previous line of code, it works perfectly, but that makes the display show as a boring checkbox instead of a neat bootstrap toggle, so that isn't a possible workaround for me. I'm using the most recent version of bootstrap-toggle, with this code in my file:

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

Also if I replace `"foo.bar"` explicitly with `"1"`, that will check the box, even with the `data-toggle="toggle"` left in. This leads me to think that it is some issue with how Vue and Bootstrap Toggle are interacting. Does anyone know what is causing this bug?

Comment: The issue is that Vue changing the `checked` binding will not trigger the DOM events that Bootstrap relies on. Consider using the Vue specific implementation of Bootstrap ~ https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/

Comment: This makes sense. I'm thinking that putting the bootstrap-vue scrips under my Vue scripts in my blade file should fix the issue, but I'm not seeing it work. Is there any other additional setup that I'd need?

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually handle things in that case.

First, you need to get a reference to the checkbox element by adding a `ref` attribute into it:

```
<input type="checkbox" ref="checkbox" :checked.prop="foo.bar">
```

Then you would need to create a watcher which manually updates the value of the toggle plugin:

```
watch: {
    'foo.bar': function(enabled) {
        $(this.$refs.checkbox).bootstrapToggle(enabled ? 'on' : 'off')
    }
},
```

And to keep the data two-way synced, you need to add a `change` event listener into the `mounted` callback function which detects if the toggle is clicked and then update the value of the `foo.bar` accordingly.

```
mounted: function() {
      $(this.$refs.checkbox).bootstrapToggle().change(function(e) {
        this.foo.bar = $(e.target).prop('checked');
      }.bind(this));
},
```

See this JS Fiddle for a complete demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/169950/

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my post, but the v-bind works perfectly fine on `foo.bar` for a normal text-style input. That indicates to me that the issue isn't with foo's implementation, but I'm not extremely well-versed in Vue so I might be wrong. But wouldn't that show that the variable is reactive?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that replicates your issue?

Comment: I suppose if I can find the time, but like I said, the reactivity works fine in all inputs except for when bootstrap is turned on for checkboxes. This doesn't strike me as the cause of the problem.

Comment: I just realized that you're pertaining to a bootstrap plugin. I have updated my answer.